# Auth0 ASP.Net.Owin SSO Validate cookie cross domain

Tags: asp.net, cookies, single-sign-on, owin, auth0

I am trying to setup SSO on my ASP.NET apps on the same domain using Auth0 & OWIN. I used the following tutorial to [setup my Owin Context](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-owin).

I configured the Auth0 cookie with a name & Domain with the *CookieAuthenticationOptions* in startup.cs:

```
string auth0Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:Domain"];
string auth0ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientId"];
string auth0ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientSecret"];

// Enable Kentor Cookie Saver middleware
app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
// Set Cookies as default authentication type
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    //Add Cross domain
    CookieName = "sso.example.com",
    CookieDomain = ".example.com",
    AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
```

My Auth0 Configuration in Startup.cs:

```
var options = new Auth0AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Domain = auth0Domain,
            ClientId = auth0ClientId,
            ClientSecret = auth0ClientSecret,
            Provider = new Auth0AuthenticationProvider
            {

                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    // Get the user's country
                    JToken countryObject = context.User["https://example.com/geoip"];
                    if (countryObject != null)
                    {
                        string countryCode = countryObject["country_code"].ToObject<string>();
                        string Lat = countryObject["latitude"].ToObject<string>();
                        string Long = countryObject["longitude"].ToObject<string>();
                        string City = countryObject["city_name"].ToObject<string>();
                        string Country = countryObject["country_name"].ToObject<string>();

                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("country_code", countryCode, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Connection));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("country_name", Country, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Connection));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("city_name", City, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Connection));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("longitude", Long, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Connection));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("latitude", Lat, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Connection));
                    }
                    JToken userMeta = context.User["https://example.com/user_metadata"];
                    if (userMeta != null)
                    {
                        string companyName = userMeta["company"].ToObject<string>();
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("company", companyName, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Connection));
                        string fullName = userMeta["full_name"].ToObject<string>();
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("full_name", fullName, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Connection));
                    }

                    JToken rolesObject = context.User["https://example.com/app_metadata"];
                    if (rolesObject != null)
                    {
                        string[] roles = rolesObject["roles"].ToObject<string[]>();
                        foreach (var role in roles)
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Connection));
                        }
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }

        };
        options.Scope.Add("openid profile"); // Request a refresh_token
```

How would I go about authenticating the client on the secondary application? The Cookie is available on the secondary application but I still have to go through the login proccess with Auth0. Am I missing something? Or is there an article I can read about the implimentation?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by copying the same *startup.cs* on both apps, and adding a [machine key](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey/) to the root Web Config file, in the **system.web** tag.

Nothing changed from my initial configuration, I just changed the domain names to my domain.

Comment: yes, applications with same application key share the same cookies